# How do I map the x co-ordinate of a pan gesture to the rotation of cube?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, 3d

I'm developing an iPhone app where the main views are presented the user on the surface of a cube. Users switch views by rotating the cube with a pan gesture.

To achieve this I am using the GKLCubeController class from [this GitHub project](https://github.com/pyro2927/GKLCubeViewController).

In terms of adding views to a cube and rotating, it works fine. However the angular rotation of the cube doesn't map correctly to the current `x` position of the finger as it pans across the screen.

The problem is that the cube rotation lags behind the finger movement by about ½ second making the cube feel ‘heavy’ as illustrated in [this short screencast](https://vimeo.com/70481217).

The code handling the rotation is shown below:

```
-(void)panHandler:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)panner{
    CGPoint translatedPoint = [panner translationInView:self.view.window];
    CGFloat halfWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width / 2.0;
    //    save our starting points
    if([panner state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        startingX = translatedPoint.x;
        if (!transformLayer) {
            transformLayer = [[CATransformLayer alloc] init];
            transformLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds;

            for (UIView *viewToTranslate in views) {
                [viewToTranslate removeFromSuperview];
                [transformLayer addSublayer:viewToTranslate.layer];
            }
            //        add in this new layer
            [self.view.layer addSublayer:transformLayer];
        }
    } else if([panner state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
       ...
    } else {
        //        instantly adjust our transformation layer
        CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
        transform.m34 = kPerspective;
        double percentageOfWidth = (translatedPoint.x - startingX) / self.view.frame.size.width;
        transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0, 0, -halfWidth);
        double adjustmentAngle = percentageOfWidth * M_PI_2 + startingAngle;
        transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, adjustmentAngle, 0, 1, 0);
        transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, 0, 0, halfWidth);
        transformLayer.transform = transform;
        finishingAngle = adjustmentAngle;
    }
}
```

I've a suspicion the problem is something to do with the conversion of the `CGPoint.x` returned by `UIPanGestureRecognizer translationInView:` to a rotation angle. Can anyone confirm whether this is the case, and suggest what the correct maths should be for mapping the touch position `x` to the rotation of a cube such that the cube edge tracks the finger motion as it pans across the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. The major performance issue here is the way this class is performing the transform of the sides of the cube. It's giving each side of the cube a complicated transform, and then as you're dragging the cube around, it's taken the relevant sides of the cube, added them to a `CATransformLayer`, and performing a complicated transform upon that layer (thus, when you look at the individual sides of the cube, you're doing a transform of a transform).

   I pulled out that `CATransformLayer` logic, and updated the transform for the individual sides, and it was dramatically more responsive.

   By the way, you may might want to still employ something like this `CATransformLayer` logic when you animate the letting go of the rotated cube, as that's an excellent way of synchronizing the animation of the individual sides of the cube (otherwise you get some separation in the sides of the cube during the animation). But while dragging, there's too much of a performance hit.

   As you continue to refine this, there are possibly other optimizations that can be done, but my testing suggests that getting rid of a transformation on a complicated transformation made a huge impact on performance.

   And, by the way, make sure to test this on a device, not the simulator, as the simulator's graphics performance is very different than that of the device.
2. A minor factor that might contribute a slight initial delay in responsiveness may be the inherent delay in `UIPanGestureRecognizer` (which looks for a certain amount of movement before recognizing the gesture as a pan, so that other gestures such as taps and the like can trigger if appropriate). It's a modest delay and a very small part of your performance problem, but for the quickest of response times, you might not want to use the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. Either subclass your own, or use a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` with a `minimumPressDuration` of `0.0`, and you can get instantaneous response to the gesture.

   You'll see this respond more quickly to movement (but it's also a gesture that doesn't play well with others, that if you have tap gestures or the like inside the view, they won't be triggered).

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed reply! I've just tried the technique using `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and `minimumPressDuration = 0.0` and there is a slight improvement, but not much. I did a test just moving a circle around the screen with `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and actually the delay is minimal compared the overhead delay when rotating the cube. I therefore tried another test, only drawing 1 side of the cube. This is shown [here](https://vimeo.com/70590042), as you can see, there is still a lag, which you don't get e.g. with the WeatherCube app. Any other ideas?

Comment: I should also add that I tested on the device, and in this case there is negligible difference between the device (iPhone 5) and the simulator performance.

Comment: @JamieBullock Hmm. Well I did a test with a cube effect, myself, and it kept up just fine (even on my test iPhone 3GS). The only thing that leaps out at me about `GKCubeController`'s implementation is that it adds all the sides to some layer and rotates that (whereas I only rotate only the two sides visible at a given moment time). Perhaps there are other issues, too. I'll take a look tomorrow.

Comment: @JamieBullock I tested that project and confirmed the performance problem: The issue is that it has four views with complicated layer transforms, and it's then adding those to a new `CATransformLayer` and doing a complex transform on that (thus doing four transforms on transforms). When I pulled that code out and updated separate transforms, one for each visible side of the cube, it was _much_ faster. It's useful to use that super layer trick when animating them back (it keeps everything nicely synchronized), but when trying to track gestures, it's just too computationally inefficient.

Comment: By the way, I tried to remedy a couple of these performance issues here: https://github.com/robertmryan/GKLCubeViewController

Comment: Wow! This is a massive improvement. Thanks so much for thinking this through.

Comment: FWIW, I also find your code more readable. Is it worth making a pull request back to the original project, do you think?